# Create a webpage that will access and effect change on a remotely held file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, ssh

I am hoping there is a way to do this but have had difficulty searching because the terms all seem too general and the results don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

I travel a lot and am often in areas where the internet on a shared computer is the ONLY method for accessing the web.  I can't use SSH or SFTP.

I would like to make a web page (hosted publicly, accessible to the world) that will 1) be password protected itself (can do that with .htaccess, pretty sure), and then 2) when logged in, will present me a list of links that IF CLICKED will rename, remove, or move files on a server that's NOT on the same server as the web page is served.

Can this be done?

Basically, with SSH I'd just ssh to Server 1 (where the web server is) and then ssh AGAIN to the Server 2 (where the files I want to access are).  Easy.  But with just access to HTTP, it seems like this is much more complex.

I suspect the method is to create public/private keys and then use some php commands to trigger processes that are tied to hyperlinks on the page?  For example:

```
<a href="/abovewebroot/deletefile001.php">Delete file 001</a>
<a href="/abovewebroot/renamefootobar.php">Rename file foo to bar</a>
```

My idea is that the "deletefile001.php" file would contain the necessary ssh and link to a bash script that does what I need it to.  That way, I wouldn't need access to SSH directly.  It would be done in advance, with the process started by clicking the link.

Lastly, what kind of security risks are there in this?  Can spiders trigger the links automatically?  I'm not worried too much about people accessing maliciously, but mainly about accidental triggering that would cause sudden loss of the files.

Any and all help would be fantastic.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a web-based FTP or SSH client, something that would be a very large task to code yourself. Here are a couple frameworks that I found after a couple minutes of Google searching. I cannot guarantee the quality or the security of any of these services, as I have not used them myself.

Open-source frameworks that you could install on your own server:

Web-based FTP framework: [Monsta FTP](http://www.monstaftp.com/)

Web-based SSH framework: [Web Console](http://www.web-console.org/)

Online services that you could use independently of your website:

Online FTP client: [net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/)

Online SSH client: [consoleFISH](http://www.serfish.com/console/)

Comment: Thanks, @Parker for the thought but no, I'm not really looking for this.  I'm not necessarily the person who will be able to go to the web page.  I'm looking for something where I can create a web page and have it execute the way I've set up above.  Not where I can use online SSH.

Comment: For instance, if I want to set up a .bash script that lets my Mom clear out her settings and start fresh, but she's not really up to the task of using anything else than the web.  Just "Go to this site" and then follow the online directions.  That's what I'm looking for.  :-)